# Giving an Element 100% width while using fixed padding

Tags: html, xhtml

I have an element with width 100% of the body and i need to be able to give it padding in pixels. every attempt i had at it ended up adding scrolling. i can't use overflow:hidden because i need to have vertical scrolling, and overflow-x/y isn't fully supported yet.

so how can i add fiexed padding to an element with a 100% width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
<body>
<div style="width:auto; background-color:#333333;height:100%; padding:10px; color:#FFFFFF;">
Example
</div>
</body>
```

I do not encourage you to use `inline styling`

Answer (score 0):

If you give padding to body (which is 100% by default), it will increase the width of the page and add scrollbars.

You need to create a DIV within body and work in it.